# Getting Error java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF When Deploying Application using JMod Plugin

Tags: java, maven, java-9, jlink, jmod

Im using OpenJDK9 and created a parent child structure to deploy the app using JLink and JMod.

I follow the jigsaw example on Internet to create my structure of App. Before I was getting path must be directory when using JMod 3.0.0-alpha-1, then i find its a bug in Plugin, 3.0.0-alpha-2-SNAPSHOT was not available yet so i build it, the path errors gone but I'm getting new error.

These error cause by the dependencies i have added in POM file, If i comment the dependencies the project build successfully, but i want to build the project with these dependencies.

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

I have uploaded the project on git also [Sample Project on GitHub](https://github.com/AKMANSoft/deploymentTest)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because one or more of your dependency have ZipException class. it a conflict in class import. You should try removing all the imports and adding it one by one.

Comment: same project build successfully once I did clean build in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you have one or more similar classes on your classpath. These classes come from dependencies defined in the `pom.xml` file.

**Suggested solution:**

First, use  [this](https://github.com/basepom/duplicate-finder-maven-plugin) plugin to check duplications in your classpath.

Then remove unnecessary dependencies from your `pom.xml` OR exclude classes or jar files. [This](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) documentation can help you.

Hope that this will help you.